# Properly initialize NSMutableString

Tags: ios, nsmutablestring

I declare an object in the beginning of M file as follows:

```
NSMutableString *SomeString;
```

And in a method I try to init it:

```
SomeString  = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%c",'0'];
NSMutableString *SomeOtherString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%c",'0'];
```

When I debug after the above line, I see that `SomeOtherString` holds the string `"0"` but `SomeString` remains empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "at the beginning of M file"? You mean outside any methods? Are you trying to declare a global variable?

Comment: yes, exactly as you said.

Comment: Can you show a more complete picture of how your .m is laid out?

Comment: Are you using ARC or manual reference counting?  What are you trying to achieve by having a global variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's because `stringWithFormat` returns an autorelease object while your `SomeString` is a global variable , so `SomeString` is out of scope and released.

try this :

```
  SomeString  = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%c",'0'];
```

Comment: Assuming ARC and that `SomeString` isn't referenced anywhere below within the scope, this seems more or less correct, though it's not exactly an issue of going out of scope per se.

Comment: Thanks for advise , but can you say more about this issue and why it is not going out of scope??I'd like to learn.

Comment: My understanding is that with ARC, the compiler is (most likely) inserting a release statement immediately after what it perceives as the last use of an object it had been retaining—this may well be earlier than when the variable leaves scope.